# Could a router firmware update affect Wi-Fi signal coverage?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I know how the question sounds, but I recently updated the firmware of my TP-Link AC1750 router and since then the Wi-Fi signal coverage has decreased: my devices (phone, laptop) @ some rooms @ my house no longer detect the Wi-Fi network (or it detects it but the signal quality is too low and it won't even connect). Before the update signal was ok everywhere.

I also checked the router settings, the "Transmit power" setting is still set to the max value ("High" in my case)

Is this just a strange coincidence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot be sure, but it's definitely possible for a firmware update to reduce coverage. One common reason would be if it was discovered that some devices were transmitting at a higher power or with a higher gain than they were supposed to be. A simple fix would be to drop the maximum power output with a firmware update.

Comment: I managed to install a custom firmware (openwrt) and played with the signal strength and my conclusion was that the firmware upgrade indeed reduced signal strength. After setting the max signal strength in the custom firmware, signal power was back as before (to be honest, even better)

Answer (score 1):

The firmware of a router can control the maximum transmit power - some have the setting openly available, with different steps of tuning, while others don't.
The transmit power can also affect the broadcasting range, however things get a bit more complicated as the noise levels also increase and distortion may be introduced as the transmitter gets overloaded.

Overall impact should not be *very* significant, especially when coming from an original firmware. Are you sure there are no other options which may adversely affect the coverage, for example a different channel being selected?

Comment: It's using the same channel (I even tried changing channels to a more free one without any interference from other wifi signals).

Answer (score 0):

Normally your wireless router should work well after an update, you have to double check if you have changed its physical location? or changed the security settings.

Try the [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.com/support/downloads/) and check channels strength with your old & new firmwares.

You just may have to change your radio channel and check with inSSIDer.

Comment: Location is the same, didn't touch it physically. Unfortunately the router doesn't allow me to downgrade the firmware. Currently looking for a solution for this